# Integrability of function related to convergence of infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

For a measurable function $f$ on $[1,\infty)$ which is bounded on bounded sets, define $a_n = \int_n^{n+1}f$ for each natural number $n$. Is it true that $f$ is integrable over $[1,\infty)$ if and only if the series $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges? Is it true that $f$ is integrable over $[1,\infty)$ if and only if the series $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely?

I've been working on this problem for awhile now and I fear I have gotten tunnel vision... I would really appreciate some help!! This is problem #29 from Royden fourth edition on page 89. My gut is telling me the if and only if holds for absolutely convergent, otherwise there may be some voodoo possible with rearranging terms or something.

Appreciate the help!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what happens with $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$.

Comment: So with this one each $a_n$ would evaluate to zero because $sin(2\pi n)=0$ for all $n$? But integrating over $f$ would still be infinite? How do I prove these things though?

Comment: No: every $a_n$ evaluates to $0$ because $-\frac1{2\pi}\cos(2\pi n)=-\frac1{2\pi}$ for all $n$. And obviously $\int_{[1,\infty)}\lvert \sin(2\pi x)\rvert\,dx=\infty$.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean every $a_n$ evaluates to $-\frac{1}{2\pi}$??? So the point is, even for absolutely convergent this doesn't work?

Comment: No, it wouldn't and yes, that is my point.